# Mostrar los iconos posibles en una Toolbar en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo dos `ToolBars` en una app, la secundaria que se muestra abajo de la principal `ActionBar` en su totalidad hay 10 botones, quiero mostrar lo máximo que permite la anchura.

Los items están definidos como `ifRoom`, que en principio se muestran todos en un `dropmenu` menos un par.

¿Cómo hago para forzar la visualización de los botones de la toolbar, teniendo en cuenta la anchura del dispositivo y si esta en posición vertical o horizontal.

La carga de los `ToolBars` lo hago así.

```
private void initToolbars() {
    Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarTop);

    Toolbar toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_bottom);
    if (toolbarBottom != null) {

        //setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);

        toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                //process the selected tool
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_firstcase:

                        return true;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar

        toolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.tools);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para detectar la orientación del dispositivo

Para obtener el ancho en `dpi`

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

Detectar orientación en vertical / portrait

```
private boolean isPortrait() {
    int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
}
```

Detectar orientación en horizontal / landscape

```
private boolean isLandscape() {
    int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
}
```

He estado realizando comprobaciones y lo mejor que se me ajusta en mi MotoG
el tamaño de los iconos más o menos, 72dpi en vertical y 60 en horizontal.

```
long total = Math.round(dpWidth / (isPortrait() ? 72 : 60));
```

Para obtener los `items` del menu

```
Menu menuTools = toolbarBottom.getMenu();
```

Y para forzar su visibilidad en la toolbar

```
if (total > menuTools.size()) total = menuTools.size();
for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
    MenuItem swap = menuTools.getItem(i);
    swap.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}
```

No ser si eso funciona con diferentes resoluciones, es decir los valores 72 y 60 digamos han sido extraídos con el método prueba error.